# adding a class to some images based on the alt text using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i add a class to some images based on the alt text using jquery?

here is an example of the image:

```
<img border="0" src="images/Product/icon/26086_1_.jpg" 
alt="Show Picture 1" onclick="setcolorpicidx_26086(1);" 
style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;">
```

so if the alt text contains "Show Picture" then add a class of `image-nav`

Comment: Ran performance of the solutions here: http://jsperf.com/test-selector-vs-filter. Chrome surprises me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use a filter :

```
$('img').filter(function() {
    return $(this).prop('alt').indexOf('Show Picture')!=-1;
}).addClass('image-nav');
```

Comment: Why use filter when there are selectors that do it?

Comment: That's why I wrote 'could also', and I'm guessing jQ does something similar internally for attribute selectors ?

Comment: ironically this "could also" has saved my day!

Comment: Only browser that seems to like this filter is Chrome, others are very slow with this solution.

Comment: A filter will be slower on most browsers, and especially in Opera, but still, my browser (chrome) can run this function 50K times a second compared to 66K times a second for the attribute selector, I would'nt call that 'very slow' as I can't really see any situation where you'd need to filter anywhere close to 50K images this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img[alt^="Show Picture"]').addClass('image-nav');
```

Uses the [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

or

```
$('img[alt*="Show Picture"]').addClass('image-nav');
```

Uses the [attribute contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the attribute [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `[name^="value"]`

```
$('img[alt^="Show Picture"]').addClass("image-nav");
```